# Generate HTML and send it as E-mail

Tags: c#, .net, xml, smtp

I have written code in C# that should transform an XML with the help of a XSL stylesheet, generate some HTML and save it locally where the XML and XSL are there, then send the HTML as e-mail.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

public class SendMail
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
     {       
       try{

         //load the Xml doc
         XPathDocument XPathDoc = new XPathDocument(@"C:\Test\svnlog.xml") ;

         XslTransform XslTrans = new XslTransform() ;

         //load the Xsl 
         XslTrans.Load(@"C:\Test\svnlog.xsl") ;

         //create the output stream
         XmlTextWriter Writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\Test\CommitReport.html", null);

        //do the actual transform of Xml
        XslTrans.Transform(XPathDoc,null, Writer);        

        Writer.Close() ;

          }
      catch(Exception ex)
    {

        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }


  using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Test\CommitReport.html"))
{                                                         
   MailMessage Mail = new MailMessage();
   Mail.To = ("pqr@dna.com "); 
   Mail.From = new MailAddress("abc@bac.com");
   Mail.Subject = ("Commit Error Report"); 
   Mail.IsBodyHtml = true;  //defines that your email is in Html form 
   Mail.BodyFormat = (@"C:\Test\CommitReport.html"); 

  Mail.Body = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
}

 //create instance of smtpclient 
 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(); 
 smtp.EnableSsl = true; 
 smtp.Send(mail);

 } 

 }

  private static void MailAddress(string p)
{
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}

 }
```

I am not sure whether the following line saves the html locally or not:

```
XmlTextWriter Writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\Test\CommitReport.html", null);
```

I am also getting a new error: "The type or namespace name 'Mail' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Have you checked in c:\Test\ if a CommitReport.html file was created?

Comment: Yeah...its not generating...is the syntax correct?

Comment: what error are you getting back. Mail.BodyFormat property is not a string. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailmessage.bodyformat.aspx

Comment: I am getting a new error:                                         "The type or namespace name 'Mail' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class is defined in the `System.Net.Mail` namespace, not `System.Web.Mail`. Your code needs some modifications. For example things like `Response.Write(ex.Message);` in a console application hardly make sense. Ensuring proper disposal of disposable resources is also important.

So try improving your code a little:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            var xPathDoc = new XPathDocument(@"C:\Test\svnlog.xml");
            var xslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
            xslTrans.Load(@"C:\Test\svnlog.xsl");
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Test\CommitReport.html"))
            {
                xslTrans.Transform(xPathDoc, null, writer);
            }

            var mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("pqr@dna.com"));
            mail.From = new MailAddress("abc@bac.com");
            mail.Subject = "Commit Error Report";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Test\CommitReport.html");

            using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.yourhost.com"))
            {
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                smtpClient.Send(mail);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Also make sure that